# Running exec() command with dev>null & doesn't work, but dev>null does

Tags: php, exec

I have this exec command which runs just fine, but doesn't free up the browser (ie. there is a php timeout issue, but the actual command continues to run):

```
exec("/usr/local/php53/bin/php csv.php $file $user > /dev/null");
```

When I run `ps auxw` I see these two running processes:

```
sh -c /usr/local/php53/bin/php csv.php /tmp/php9Pwu9e 294  >
/usr/local/php53/bin/php csv.php /tmp/php9Pwu9e 294
```

However, when I run the code below, the browser immediately is free, but the command doesn't continue to run:

```
exec("/usr/local/php53/bin/php csv.php $file $user > /dev/null &");
```

When I run  `ps auxw` I see one running process that dies after 16 seconds (and seems to eat up memory quickly and use a lot of CPU%):

```
/usr/local/php53/bin/php csv.php /tmp/php9Pwu9e 294
```

Then the process dies without having actually done anything. Not sure what the ampersand is doing that would cause this.

Also why does `sh -c` appear when no ampersand is present at the end? I feel that this may be indicative of something, but have no idea what.

**EDIT:**

Because this keeps cropping up as an answer, 
I have also tried:

```
exec("/usr/local/php53/bin/php csv.php $file $user > /dev/null 2>&1 &");
```

Which demonstrates the same issue as mentioned above.
The code below, does run, but does NOT free up the browser.

```
exec("usr/local/php53/bin/php csv.php $file $user > /dev/null 2>&1");
```

Comment: Try to redirect errors to /dev/null too: `your_command > /dev/null 2>&1 &`

Comment: Yea, I've already attempted that, no go.

Comment: What happen if you directly run `php csv.php file user` in terminal?

Comment: It runs properly, the only thing that seems to be throwing it off is the ending ampersand.

Comment: What exactly is the issue?

Comment: @SalmanA the process isn't actually doing anything. it just builds up memory and uses up CPU% then dies, when it has the ampersand.

Comment: Tried shell_exec instead?

Comment: @monkeymatrix yes, and proc_open and passthru. All the same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was much simpler than I had thought. The problem was the `$file` (which was an uploaded file being stored in the `/tmp` directory) was not found. I'm not sure why, but I imagine it has something to do with the file being destroyed before the background process can get to it.

The solution was to `move_uploaded_file()` the file to a permanent location, and run the script with that file. That worked.

Answer (score 0):

try this instead

exec("nohup php csv.php $file $user > /dev/null &");

Comment: Nope, that seems to prevent anything from happening.

Comment: You also need to include fab's suggestion of sending errors to /dev/null.

Answer (score 0):

Try both redirecting both the output and the errors to `/dev/null` (or another output file of your choice, provided that it has write permissions set for the user running the web server), as well as making it a background process with the ampersand, as stated on a [PHP manual user note](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php#101506):

```
<?php

exec("php /var/www/foo.php > /dev/null 2>&1 &");
```

Just tried it and it works as expected: the calling script finishes right away, and the background process keeps running for as long as it takes to complete.

Comment: As stated in the comments, I've tried this approach to no avail.